# Was "King Arthur & the Knights of the Round Table" released in English on DVD?

Tags: arthurian

This show "King Arthur & the Knights of the Round Table" ("Entaku no Kishi Monogatari Moero Āsā"), was one of my favourties as a kid back in the 80s. Does anyone know if it was released in English on DVD?

Comment: seems like it released in some form (not sure how official or complete) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Arthur-Entaku-Kishi-Monogatari-dubbed/dp/B001AM14EI

Comment: not sure why this is getting close votes. Arthur is on topic

Comment: @NKCampbell - Simple shopping questions are off-topic, regardless of how topical the property is. In this case the answer is "Yes, and you can buy it on Amazon".

Comment: @Valorum - I see it less as 'where can I go get this and have it delivered to me?' vs 'was a translation ever produced and released?' - an entirely valid answer could be "yes, out of print", "no - never", "yes - in print to this day" - same as if asking if the Star Wars Holiday Special was ever released on DVD (to my mind anyway)

Comment: @NKCampbell - Given that it was answerable with a simple google search, to my mind it falls into the category of a shopping question. At the very least it shows no research effort whatsoever

Comment: oh agree w/ the research part @Valorum, that's why I downvoted, but not vtc :)

Comment: @NKCampbell just to respond, I have been searching for this product both online, and in rare comic/anime stores globally for the last 10 years. It was a simple question to see as I may have missed something all this time. I didn't realise this place would be a social media outlet for small minded people to insult a person, which means it is for children who simply want to make statements, share their opinions and not actually be helpful in anyway.

Comment: I don't believe anyone intended to be insulting Ahmed, if that was the outcome, I apologize. This site does have some expectations around quality of questions and such (feel free to browse the help and meta pages for more info on that). If the information re: your research and efforts for 10 years had been included, that might have been valuable to downvoters that didn't realize that you had indeed done some due diligence prior to asking :)